# How to add values to keys inside an object in an array from other array in javascript

Tags: javascript

**I have an array like below**
I am trying to add some value by replacing null inside the object inside the array.
The values I wanted to add is from different array "y"

```
let toBesubmitted = [
        {a: null, id: "a"},
        {b: null, id: "b"},
        {c: null, id: "c"},
        {d: null, id: "d"},
        {e: null, id: "e"}
      ]
```

Another array

```
let y= ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"]
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using a forEach loop on the array and assigning a value to the `item[item.id]` property at a specific `index` of the y array:

```js
let toBesubmitted = [
        {a: null, id: "a"},
        {b: null, id: "b"},
        {c: null, id: "c"},
        {d: null, id: "d"},
        {e: null, id: "e"}
      ]

let y= ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"]

toBesubmitted.forEach((item, index) => item[item.id] = y[index]||null);

console.log(toBesubmitted)
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the reliance on index. Rest is good. If indices change, this fails

Comment: @AdityaParab And how else would you do it?

Comment: How do you suggest changing it to make sure that it doesn't fail?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir check my answer.

Comment: Your answer only works provided the OP will actually make an array of objects based on the first letter of a word in another array, how is that any better?

Comment: @LucaKiebel: That is the assumption here. My answer works even if you change sequence of elements in either of the arrays. As long as first letter if of each element in y has an object in toBesubmitted that has the same key, this works.

Comment: You can use `y[index] || null` like `toBesubmitted.forEach((item, index) => item[item.id] = y[index] || null);`. So that if array `y` has less number of values then it will assign `null` again instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @Karan yes, great idea ;-)

Comment: What to do if we don't have id?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *don't have id*?

Comment: Is there a chance that an element from that array has neither an ID, nor the id's value as a key?

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop would do it, if `toBeSubmitted[0].a` should be `y[0]` and the `id` property tells us which property to set:

```
for (let i = 0; i < toBesubmitted.length; ++i) {
    toBesubmitted[i][toBesubmitted[i].id] = y[i];
}
```

Example:

```js
let toBesubmitted = [
    {a: null, id: "a"},
    {b: null, id: "b"},
    {c: null, id: "c"},
    {d: null, id: "d"},
    {e: null, id: "e"}
];

let y = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"];

for (let i = 0; i < toBesubmitted.length; ++i) {
    toBesubmitted[i][toBesubmitted[i].id] = y[i];
}

console.log(toBesubmitted);
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Wow, how did I miss that? Fixed, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer though but try this:

```
    //print object
toBesubmitted.forEach(function(element, key){
    for(let e in element){
        if(e == Object.keys(element)[0])
            element[e] = y[key];
    }
});
Console.log(toBesubmitted);
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `toBesubmitted[index][key]` is `y[index][0]`
This answer doesn't rely on index being in a particular order.

```
let toBesubmitted = [
  { a: null, id: "a" },
  { b: null, id: "b" },
  { c: null, id: "c" },
  { d: null, id: "d" },
  { e: null, id: "e" }
];

let y= ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"];

y.forEach( c => {
  const prop = toBesubmitted.find(tbs => tbs.id === c[0]);
  if(prop){
    prop[c[0]] = c;
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe those were just examples by OP. `y` could have been `[ "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaaa", "bbbb", "dog" ]`. I don't think they are assigned based on the first character.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use reduce function like below;

```
let toBesubmitted = [
{a: null, id: "a"},
{b: null, id: "b"},
{c: null, id: "c"},
{d: null, id: "d"},
{e: null, id: "e"}
];

let y = ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"];

toBesubmitted.reduce( (acc,curr,idx) => curr[curr.id] = y[idx], {} );

console.log(toBesubmitted);
```

Comment: But why would you? There is no reason to use reduce here.

Comment: It has shorter syntax, using higher order function, using existing capabilities of JS, ...

Comment: Using existing capabilities of JS would be using a simple loop. The syntax also isn't shorter than other answers that are using a loop.

Comment: You could also use most other Arrow functions, but that doesn't really warrant an answer. These functions have their time and place, but it's not really here. Just to make it clear, I did not downvote your answer.

Answer (score -2):

EDITED

```js
let toBesubmitted = [
    {a: null, id: "a"},
    {b: null, id: "b"},
    {c: null, id: "c"},
    {d: null, id: "d"},
    {e: null, id: "e"}
]

let y= ["apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "elephant"]

toBesubmitted.forEach((item, index) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        if (item[key] === null) {
            item[key] = y[index];
        }
    })
})

console.log(toBesubmitted);
```

Comment: The `null` property is not always `a`.